# How to implement an event system

Tags: c#, performance, events

Im trying to implement an Event System for a game, where there are classes that can fire or handle an event wheter or not they implement these interfaces:

```
public interface IGameEvent<T> where T : EventArgs
{
     event EventHandler<T> OnEvent;
}

public interface IGameHandler<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    void OnEvent(object sender, T e);
}
```

everything looked great until i realized that no class can implement more than 1 IGameEvent because it would cause duplicate declaration,

Here is an example:

```
public class Event
{
    public KeyPressEvent OnKeyPress;
    public UpdateEvent OnUpdate;

    public void AddHadler<T>(IGameEvent<T> eEvent , IGameHandler<T> eHandler) where  T : EventArgs
    {
        eEvent.OnEvent += eHandler.OnEvent;
    }

    public void RemoveHandler<T>(IGameEvent<T> eEvent, IGameHandler<T> eHandler) where T : EventArgs
    {
        eEvent.OnEvent -= eHandler.OnEvent;
    }
}
```

KeyPressEvent:

```
public class KeyPressEvent : IGameEvent<KeyPressEvent.KeyPressedEventArgs>
{
    public class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public KeyPressedEventArgs(Keys key)
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public Keys Key { get; private set; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> OnEvent;

    private void OnCheckForKeyPressed()  //Example
    {
        if (OnEvent != null) 
            OnEvent(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(Keys.Space));
    }
}
```

Would be better to manually store the suscribers in a list in the EventSystem ?

How slower or faster than this approach that would be?

Thanks!

Comment: Events are not classes; they are a type of class member along with Properties and Methods.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? What you've got here is not a good approach, but it's very difficult to talk about potential right approaches without the context of what problem you're trying to solve. (For example: You've tagged this with "performance" - but what's the performance issue here? This approach and those in my answer are all "fast enough" - depending on the context.)

Comment: I think you're looking for this.. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can use the existing event model in C#, it might not always give you the flexibility that you require.

You can for instance not sort events based on their priority, clear events of a specific type or add a queued/delayed event.

Example)

[image: EventManager]

To signup for an event the object needs a method with the same signature as the CallbackMethod delegate.
The call might look like this:

```
class SomeObject
{
    private void OnDamageTaken(object sender, IGameEvent e)
    {
        ...
    }

    ... void Initialize()
    {
        ...
        EventManager.Subscribe("EVENT_PLAYERINJURED", this.OnDamageTaken);
        ...
    }
}

//Somewhere in the application
EventManager.Notify("EVENT_PLAYERINJURED", new PlayerInjuredEvent(...));
```

If you don't like using hardcoded eventIds everywhere you could introduce a property on your game event classes.

```
public PlayerInjuredEvent : IGameEvent
{
    public static string EventType
    {
            get
            {
                return "EVENT_PLAYERINJURED";
            }
    }
}
```

Now you can write:

```
EventManager.Notify(PlayerInjuredEvent.EventType, ...
```

I hope this gives you some ideas on how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're basically re-inventing `event` here. Your entire system is basically an ugly re-implementation of the existing `event` infrastructure in C#. You should try and use `event` directly instead.

Or you could even consider doing what most games do, which is to simply use methods instead of events. Have an `Update` method and (if you like) a `KeyPress` method. Then just call those methods. Very, very simple. This is preferable over events for frame-based simulations (anything with an `Update`/`Draw` loop).

(Personally I like to make key-press information available globally (not architecturally perfect, but extremely practical), or passed into an `Update` method as an argument, rather than as a separate method call.)

Along the lines of the of methods, if you're finding you have too many methods, you might want to consider [a component-aggregation architecture](http://cowboyprogramming.com/2007/01/05/evolve-your-heirachy/).